# Get the height of an image after changing the src

Tags: javascript, image

I have an `img` element with an empty `src` attribute. The `src` of this image is changed dynamically (depending on the page the user is going to).

Then I need to retrieve the height of the image (without jQuery).

Here is my code:

```js
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");

myImg.src = "http://lorempicsum.com/rio/350/200/1";

console.log(myImg.height); // 0 (Expected : 200)
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="myImg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to get the `height` just after you set the `src` and the image hasn't had time to download yet. You need to wait until the image is loaded and then get the `height` using the more appropriate [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), which takes CSS rules into account.

```js
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");

// Set up a load event callback, which won't run until the image
// has been fully downloaded to the client.
myImg.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // Use getComputedStyle() to get the most accurate information
  console.log(getComputedStyle(myImg).height); // "200px"
});

// Only after you've configured the load callback function should you change the source.
myImg.src = "http://lorempicsum.com/rio/350/200/1";
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="myImg">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that the image has loaded successfully before you access it's `height` and `width` dimension attributes.

This can be achieved by adding a `load` event handler to your `img` element. **Note**: you must add the event listener before setting the `src` attribute, to ensure that the load handler will be called after image loading begins.

Another characteristic of the `load` event as shown below is that the event will be called each time that the `img` element successfully loads an image. You can therefore change the `src` attribute on the img dynamically and which will cause that same `load` event handler to be called:

```js
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");

// Add event listener before setting src attribute
myImg.addEventListener('load', function() {

  console.log(myImg.height); // 0 (Expected : 200)
})



// This code is added to show how the load event handler
// is still called even when images are switched dynamically
setInterval(function() {

  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    myImg.src = "http://lorempicsum.com/rio/350/200/1";
  }
  else {
    myImg.src = "https://lorempicsum.com/rio/350/200/2"
  }
  
  console.log(myImg.src)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" id="myImg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap the code needed to load and wait for it to load into a promise for easier reusability:

```js
//Promise based loading routine
function loadImg(url) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      var tempImg = new Image;
      tempImg.src = url;
      
      function load() { 
        tempImg.removeEventListener('load', load);
        tempImg.removeEventListener('error', error);
        resolve(tempImg);
      }

      function error(evt) { 
        tempImg.removeEventListener('load', load);
        tempImg.removeEventListener('error', error);
        reject(evt);
      }

      // Add event listener before setting src attribute
      tempImg.addEventListener('load', load);
      tempImg.addEventListener('error', error);
    }
  )
}


// Example of using promise based loading routine
var displayImg = document.getElementById('main');
var info = document.getElementById('info');

loadImg('https://images.pexels.com/photos/768473/pexels-photo-768473.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500').then(img => {
  displayImg.src = img.src;
  info.textContent = img.width+' x '+img.height;
}).catch(err => console.log(err));


setTimeout(() => {
  loadImg('https://images.pexels.com/photos/768473/pexels-photo-peg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500').then(img => {
    displayImg.src = img.src;
    info.textContent = img.width+' x '+img.height;
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}, 4000);
```

```html
<img id="main"/>
<span id="info"></span>
```